# When merging in github action, the github action of the merged branch is not triggered

Tags: github, github-actions

What I want to do is this.

When a push is made to the main branch, I merge it into main2. And the github actions written in main and main2 are working.

Here is this code.

**Merge.yml**

```
name: Merge

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  merge:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Merge to main2
        run: |
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git config user.email "actions@github.com"
          git checkout main2
          git merge --allow-unrelated-histories main --no-ff --no-edit
          git push origin main2
```

**main.yml**

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  print:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Print Message
        run: echo "Hello, GitHub Actions!"
```

**main2.yml**

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main2

jobs:
  print:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Print Message
        run: echo "Hello, GitHub Actions! 22"
```

If I checkout and push to main2 on my PC, it works fine.

However, when I push from github action, it doesn't work.

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: From that other Q&A: you have to either use a PAT, or trigger on `workflow_run`.